# Multiple values in a column for a data base design

Tags: sql, database-design

I need to design a database. I have 2 entities which I must implement in SQL schema. 
The first one, is a football player.

**Football players** have :

- a unique ID
- name
- surname
- **teams he had played before and its contract date**

The second entity is Team.
**Teams** have:

- A unique name
- Date Created
- Home Stadium

How can I store many teams and its contract date in one column . Should I create a new table and how is this going to be linked ? Any Suggestions...

Comment: Can a player play for more then one team at the same time period?

Answer (score 1):

You **shouldn't** make a this kind of design! this is bad DB design and will most defiantly come back to bite you in the S.

Concatenated string is very hard to deal with, especially for beginners .

My advice is - Either make another table containing something like `Player_id,Team_id,Start_date,End_date`
,
 or just store them in the Football players table, but with a record for each old team by making the `PK` - `Player_id,Team_id,Start_Date`

Comment: the first advice seems good. about the second , player_id is a unique primary key , so i am not sure i can have multiple values with the same player id

Comment: I know, I meant change the PK to `Player_ID,Old_Team` @HakiTerror

Comment: I completely agree to this answer. You will need to have a third intermediate table with foreign keys to the Player and Team tables (and fields for the contract date).

Comment: Why `Old_Team` and not `Team_Id`? Also, why `Start_d` when you can `Start_Date`? one last thing - add the start_date as a part of the composite primary key - a player can switch teams back and forth so it's possible for a person to play for the same team for two different time periods.

Comment: Ahh, the correct answer to the question "why are there bugs in my software?" :-)

Comment: Huh yea:P I never use this kind of names though.

Answer (score 0):

Relation between tables are many to many. For this reason you must create table football_teams with 2 columns :
 `football_id and teams_id` .

So you put team id with its contracts per record in table.